# Admin client not registering to spring boot admin server

Tags: dashboard, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I have created personal microservice and registered it to spring boot admin. Its working fine. But when I applied same dependency and properties in my organisation project then admin clients are not registering to spring boot admin server.
Even though both have same properties and dependencies, why my microservice is not registering

I tried creating spring boot admin server and trying to register admin clients on this server.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a small project where I'm connecting MSs to a spring boot admin server. Had some problems (my clients would not connect to the server) and that's how I ended up here.
From what you provided, it is very difficult to pinpoint the exact problem, so there will be a lot of guessing on my part. I can only share my experience in hope it can help you too. In the end, the problem for me was the configuration parameter

```
spring.boot.admin.client.url=...
```

which was misspelled... And since this will not raise any error messages, it took some time to fix.

Go through following steps:

1. add client dependencies:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. guessing you are using actuator, make sure there is a dependency

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
3. expose actuator endpoints (probably not all like in my example) in application.properties

   ```
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
   ```
4. point your MS client to the admin server (use correct url!)

   ```
    spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:9080
   ```
5. make sure your admin server has following dependencies

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```
6. make sure your admin server has the following annotation in the main class

   ```
    @EnableAdminServer
   ```
7. make sure both server and client(s) are running correctly and can bind defined ports (change the default port if they run on the same machine - in the application.properties)

   ```
    server.port=...
   ```

If there is no additional security level, these steps should be enough to connect client to the server. With security I have no experience, but the online documentation did seem straight forward.

In the end, you can always try to build a new MS with nothing except actuator and client, and try to connect it to the server. If nothing else, it will maybe provide insight which side is broken.

Without more details it is very difficult to provide more help.

Oh yeah, I do remember one more detail: I was mixing up versions of the spring boot and JDK and since JDK17 (and spring boot version >= 3.x)  moved from javax to jakarta, had some problems with running the MS. But those errors were easy to fix from log info.